# Sendmail dnsbl whitelist for envelop from domain

Tags: dns, sendmail, dnsbl

I use dnsbl feature in Sendmail. I also use the delay_check feature and set whitelist in access_db, below is the sample

```
Connect:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx OK
From:xxx.com RELAY.
```

What I want to do is add domain xxx.com to dnsbl's whitelist and sub domain of xxx.com just use the normal check.

When I user [From:xxx.com RELAY], all of the sub domain will be white, is there anyway to avoid it ?

Thank you

Comment: **Do not** allow relaying based on envelope sender (`From:xxx RELAY`).  Envelope sender is easy to spoof, it makes your server an open relay.

Comment: Do you want to allow relaying based on sending host reverse DNS records (closed `PTR` - `A` loop)?